# Android 10: exitTransition resets after returning to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-animation, android-10.0

I'm setting up enter and exit transitions in my activities like this:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    (...)

    endSlide = new Slide(Gravity.END);

    endSlide.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
    endSlide.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);

    getWindow().setExitTransition(endSlide);
    getWindow().setReenterTransition(endSlide);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(endSlide);
}
```

which works completely fine up until API level 29. However, on API level 29 the activity transitions behave like `getWindow().setExitTransition(endSlide)` hasn't been called — but *only* after returning to an activity, meaning that:

---

Activity `A` ➔ Activity `B` (normal transition)

Activity `B` ➔ Activity `C` (normal transition)

Activity `C` ➔ Activity `B` (normal transition)

Activity `B` ➔ Activity `A` (default transition)

---

Does anybody have any idea why that might be happening or how I can fix this?